# A few git usage questions

Tags: git

1. say I create a branch, then merge into master, then realize things went wrong.  How can I revert back to before I merged?
2. say I create a branch, work on it, and then go to merge and get allot of conflicts.   Say I don't want to deal with it and make the new branch the master now, how can I do this?

BTW, what's the best tutorial you've seen online with real life GIT usage patterns?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you merged and don't want that commit, the proper command is

   ```
   git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
   ```

   This means to reset the branch to where it was before (read up on the {} syntax - you can get most info by reading about git reflog). `HEAD^1` will work as well but you have to be aware that you are specifying the first parent of the current commit.

   Careful to notify everyone if you pushed this commit already. Don't do it if you don't have the ability to communicate a future forced update of a branch in a shared repository.
2. The proper way to do this is to merge again, but this time do it from the new branch and specify that you want only your side. "Theirs" strategy has been deprecated.

   ```
   git merge -s ours master
   ```

   then update master to where the other branch is:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge --ff-only otherbranch
   ```

   Or, instead, since you know this is going to be a fast-forward merge (the above is just a safety check), you can just update the master to the current commit without checking it out:

   ```
   git update-ref refs/heads/master HEAD
   ```

   and you can continue on working on your branch. If you were going to work on master, then use the previous commands.
3. Here are some links that I found useful:

   [gitready.com](http://www.gitready.com/)
   [Commuinity Git Book](http://book.git-scm.com/)
   [Pro Git Book](http://progit.org/book/)
   [my article](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?QuickID=1008091)

   Other sources:

   [IRC channel on freenode](http://webchat.freenode.net/)
   [Twitter Search waterfall](http://twitter.com/#!/search/%23git)

   You can also find me on twitter under the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

1. If it was not pushed, check out the master, then use `git reset --hard` with the name of the last good commit. Alternatively, use the reflog: `HEAD@{1}` will take you back to where you were previously. If it was pushed, use `git-revert` to create a new commit with your corrections.
2. Check out the master, then use `git reset --hard mybranch`. This makes master point to the same commit as mybranch, in essence throwing away all the work on master since the branches diverged. Again, if the work on master was made public it is a bad idea to throw it away.
3. See [Git Development Strategy for Small Team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331680/git-development-strategy-for-small-team).

Comment: It’s not specified whether it was pushed.

Comment: That's kind of implied for the master branch. But OK.

Answer (score 0):

1. say I create a branch, then merge into master, then realize things went wrong. How can I revert back to before I merged?

   1. If you have not pushed onto the mainline or have pushed and know absoutely sure that no one else has pulled from the mainline then do:

      git reset --hard HEAD~N (N being the number of commits you'd like to go back.)
   2. If you have pushed and or can't be sure no one else has not pulled then own up to your mistake and do:

      git revert
2. say I create a branch, work on it, and then go to merge and get allot of conflicts. Say I don't want to deal with it and make the new branch the master now, how can I do this?

   ```
   git checkout <desired branch>


   git branch -d master


   git branch -m <desired branch> master
   ```
3. BTW, what's the best tutorial you've seen online with real life GIT usage patterns?

   http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score -1):

1. http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html
2. for merging `git reset --hard` is enough, for rebasing, you will have to do `git rebase --abort`